Shower Drain Cover Installation/Replacement
We have shower drain cover which isn't quite anchored to the shower floor and keeps moving out. We're looking to make it anchored. After removing the existing cover/hair catcher, this is what we see. Wondering what products we should buy and how to install?


Leaving aside any code (you don't tell us where you are) and dimensional issues (no scale), I'd consider trying to find a shower drain flange and inserting it there.
